# Assigning tags to a post from front end using tag-it plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, http-post, frontend, tag-it

Tag-it is a jquery UI plugin that allows assigning tags, exactly like tags system in stackoverflow. https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

My goal is to allow members of my wordpress site to post from front end. To do so, I have created a form with input fields. I get the input content using `$_POST['something']`.To insert the post data (title, content, custom fields values), I use `wp_insert_post` function, and it is working well.

And to insert tags for the specific post I use `wp_set_object_terms` function (since I am using custom post type and a taxonomy for tags). This last function is working well if I assign some sample values to it but I cant get the input values of the tags input created by `tag-it`. I tried my best to link between the plugin and the PHP code responsible of assigning tags to my post in WP DB.

In fact, in my code source I put:

```
<ul id="myTags">
</ul>
```

And this code is transformed by the plugin (after execution) to :

```
<ul id="myTags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<li class="tagit-new">
<input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I retrieve the POST variable from this input field as an array, so that I can put it in the parameters of `wp_set_object_terms` ?

Your usual help is always appreciated.

Comment: I would like to recommend [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `fieldName` parameter to `tagit` function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit(
        {
        fieldName: "tages[]"
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Now I can echo  `$_POST['tages'];` since the HTML after execution became:

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="d" name="tages">
```

In addition, `$_POST['tages'];` is a PHP array which I can directly put in second parameter of `wp_set_object_terms`.

Thank you very much, some problems take a lot of time to resolve, but only before posting them on SO.